# How to prepared array based on dividable value from length of people array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, divide

Below is an array of people IDs

```
var arrPeopleIDs = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

I'd like to separate it into groups of N or less starting from the end of array.

people: 5
divide: single/double (N = 2)

- 1 key for single with 1
- 1 key for double with 2,3
- 1 key for double with 4,5

```
// Below output expected
var arrResult = [
 [1], [2,3], [4,5]
];
```

people: 5
divide: single/double/triple (N = 3)

- 1 key for double with 1,2
- 1 key for triple with 3,4,5

```
// Below output expected
var arrResult = [
 [1,2], [3,4,5]
];
```

people: 5
divide: single/double/triple/quad (N = 4)

- 1 key for single with 1
- 1 key for quad with 2,3,4,5

```
// Below output expected
var arrResult = [
 [1], [2,3,4,5]
];
```

Can someone please help me with the expected output?

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: What's the logic, and what have you tried?

Comment: The logic is the chunk is back to front, by the biggest number, by the looks of it

Comment: I don't understand the results. The first one seems logical but the second suggests that you are trying to fit the people into the groups yet the criteria become unclear. Why is `[1, 2, 3], [4,5]` not correct there? And the third one is even stranger - `[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]` is not the result?

Comment: @VLAZ take the largest number (ie single|double|triple => triple) and chunk the array backwards, if possible. If not possible, take the value before the largest and repeat

Comment: @Kobe your are right! can you please help with the logic for it?

Comment: @Kobe ok, that makes more sense. So, make the least amount of chunks using the largest possible chunks for the last elements. The question wasn't really clear on the rules.

Comment: You should also show what you have tried, like Jack has suggested. And please edit your post instead of just answering in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will only ever be one remainder while chunking like this, so you can safely chunk the array, then add the remainder, if there is any:

```js
var arrPeopleIDs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const chunk = (arr, d) => {
  const temp = arr.slice()
  const out = []
  const rem = temp.length % d

  while (temp.length !== rem) out.unshift(temp.splice(temp.length - d, d))
  rem && out.unshift(temp.splice(0, rem))

  return out
}

console.log(chunk(arrPeopleIDs, 1))
console.log(chunk(arrPeopleIDs, 2))
console.log(chunk(arrPeopleIDs, 3))
console.log(chunk(arrPeopleIDs, 4))
console.log(chunk(arrPeopleIDs, 5))
```

Above, is a function that will take an array, and a number - which is the max size of the chunk - and return a chunked array, starting with biggest chunks from the end of the array, then the remainder at the start. This function will not modify the original array - so it can be called multiple times

Comment: Assuming the array has a length of 5, yes. But for e.g. [1,2,3,4,5,6] and single/double/triple this would fail. Anyhow it fits the sample provided by the OP.

Comment: @assoron Im not sure it would? Check my edit - I added another element to the array

Comment: It would return `[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ] ]`, wouldn't it? Because the remainder after the first iteration would still be `3`.

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly simple to create a function that takes an array of values, and an array of sizes, and chunk based on that.

```js
function chunkLargest(arr, chunks) {
  let currentChunk = chunks.pop();
  let r = [];
  arr.reverse();
  while (arr.length > 1) {
    if (currentChunk > arr.length) {
      currentChunk = chunks.pop();
    }
    r.push(arr.splice(0, currentChunk));
  }
  return r.reverse().map(e => e.reverse());
}

console.log(chunkLargest([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

How it works:

First, you take the starting chunk size (the last value of the `chunks` array) with `pop` to modify the array, and define a result array. Then you loop while the original array still has elements, check if you need to change the chunk size, and chunk the array.

If you want it to be reusable, to ensure the original array doesn't get modified, you could use a shallow copy inside the function:

```js
function chunkLargest(a, chunks) {
  let arr = [...a];
  let currentChunk = chunks.pop();
  let r = [];
  arr.reverse();
  while (arr.length > 1) {
    if (currentChunk > arr.length) {
      currentChunk = chunks.pop();
    }
    r.push(arr.splice(0, currentChunk));
  }
  return r.reverse().map(e => e.reverse());
}

const arrPeopleIDs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

console.log(chunkLargest(arrPeopleIDs, [1, 2, 3]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: This works, but I think this is in the wrong order, though.

Comment: Really @Kobe? Looks fine to me...what in particular do you think is wrong? It starts from the last value in the chunks array, working towards the first value, in the same order as the OP specified.

Comment: I think that the largest chunks should be at the end of the array, like in OP's examples. Although I may be wrong.

Comment: Oh, right. My bad. I'll just `reverse` the starting array then.

Comment: That might work, but i think you'd subsequently have to reverse all of the chunks? Not sure, give it a try.

Comment: Yeah, reversing on both ends was the way to go - better now?

Comment: Yeah, nicely done.

Comment: If your array parameter is a variable it will get changed from inside the function: `const arrPeopleIDs = [1,2,3,4,5]; chunkLargest(arrPeopleIDs, [1, 2, 3]);
console.log(arrPeopleIDs) // => []`, add `let a = [...arr]` and work from there?

Comment: How will that help @assoron?

Comment: Right now if you call the function with a saved variable as your array parameter your array will get changed. I am not sure whether side effects like that are wanted so I'd make a proper copy of the parameter array and work from there. My example above is just illustrating that the original used array would become an empty array after it is used to call the function.

Comment: Yeah, that's because JS is pass-by-reference when it comes to objects/arrays IIRC. That's the simplest way to avoid the issue, just shallow-copying the array inside the function.

Comment: That's my point, yes. Avoid side-effects.